# Jibx Codegen class not found

Tags: java, code-generation, jibx

I'm trying to run Jibx CodeGen in the command line to generate Java source files from xml schema (xsd) files. However, it seems I'm not even able to run CodeGen. I know I should provide at least the input xsd as parameter, but CodeGen crashes before, so it does not matter here.

```
java -cp "~/.m2/repository/org/jibx/jibx-tools/1.2.3/jibx-tools-1.2.3.jar" org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
Could not find the main class: org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen.  Program will exit.
```

I've opened the jar and it seems the class package is correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to run JiBX codegen:
1. Run it as a maven plugin.
2. Run it standalone.

I highly recommend running JiBX as a maven plugin. You will find lots of documentation and examples at: http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/index.html

If you want to run JiBX as a stand-alone program, you will need to have all the executable jars in the same directory. You can simplify your setup by downloading the entire package from our sourceforge page at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jibx/